# os.environ['PATH'] does not work when running Python code from command-line

Tags: python, environment-variables

Why does the following not work?

```
$ python -c 'import os; print os.environ['PATH']'
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'PATH' is not defined
```

whereas

```
$ python

>>> import os
>>> print os.environ['PATH']
```

works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes. Try:

```
python -c 'import os; print os.environ["PATH"]'
```

The shell is stripping out the single quotes before the command gets to Python, as you can see with the following command:

```
echo 'import os; print os.environ['PATH']'
```

(In fact, you can see by the *syntax coloring* here that something weird is going to happen.)

Now, why does this happen? The single quotes around `PATH` end a string and start a new one. Essentially, the shell is parsing it as the following three strings (although without the line breaks):

```
import os; print os.environ[
PATH
]
```

And that's what gets passed to Python, which sees `PATH` as a variable name, and rightly complains that you haven't defined it.

For more information on using your shell, see `man bash`. ("How do I use my shell?" is not, strictly speaking, a Python question, or even a programming question.)